# Pipe email in PHP

Tags: php, shell

I would like to **pipe email through a PHP script**.

To be recognized has a script to be execute by Shell, I've put that line a the begining of my file:
`#!/usr/bin/php -q`

**I've enabled PHP's Mail Parse extension.**

I have 2 issues:

1. If I move my script into a sub directory, any email can't be piped, despite of the new valid patch set in my c-panel (Seems like PHP IO stream can't be read in sub directories?). Otherwise, I can pipe email in */public_html* (where my php.ini file is), but I'm still unable to call a Mail Parse's function that directory.
2. My script seems to use another php.ini file, because when I call a function from **Mail Parse**, PHP warns me that the function is undefined (if I use another script manually, in the same directory and same code, all works and there's no warning.). I've put that line to use a specific php.ini file `#!/usr/bin/php -c /homeXX/XXXX/public_html/php.ini`. It didn't worked.

Thanks for any answer, it'll be very appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't make assumptions as to what the current working directory is. Can't see your code, so that's the only advice I can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Depending of server configuration, you have to avoid space between command line option (`-c`) and path (`/path/to/script`). That solution worked in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Setting up stuff in your php.ini ist one thing.

I think you need to install pear/pecl and the mailparse package to make it work.

Depending on you linux flavor you can do that with (debian/ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear

sudo pecl install mailparse
```

and your php.ini needs the path to pear (if not already set) in 
Path and Directories section.

take a look at the manual about [mailparse](http://php.net/manual/en/mailparse.installation.php)

Comment: Thanks Michael D for your suggestions!

 
I'm working directly in a PHP script, here's what I did:

1. In my c-panel, I've set a **path** to a PHP script to pipe email.
2. **In my PHP script**, I've added hashbag line to specify that Shell have to execute my script.

I've tried your suggestions, Michael D, but nothing resolved, same sad problem:

1. PHP warning of undefined function.
2. Bouce-back email from my hosting to warn me of delivery fail.

If you need my script, I can paste it!

Comment: I already have Mail Parse extension installed and enabled. My php.ini file is updated and works. I've tested 2 things:

1. I've tested my code in a single PHP script by my browser.

2. Added the same code into me PHP file called by shell.

The first try works, the second doesn't.

Comment: I add that line to my shell called PHP script to execute the other one after

`#!/usr/bin/php -f /homeXX/XXXX/public_html/parser.php`

So, I want that my called script is executed then parser.php to be executed, is it valid?

Comment: hard to tell. can you add/post your code in the question?

Comment: Sorry for unreadable code, I can't update my question..

#!/usr/bin/php /homeXX/XX/public_html/parser.php
<?php
$sock = fopen ("php://stdin", 'r');
$email = '';
while (!feof($sock))
    $email .= fread($sock, 1024);
fclose($sock);
file_put_contents('test.txt', $email);
?>

Which command can I use to execute the script above THEN execute parser.php (other script to be call after the first one)?

Comment: either use a bash script and call both php files directly with just #!/usr/bin/php -c /path/php.ini as shebang in php file or use exec in the first php file to call the second php file - or include it and call methods